# ASP.NET MVC 4 Submit from 2 partials on same view invokes both action methods for each submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am brand new to .NET MVC Programming - and have been stuck here with no where to go:

2 Models representing 2 tables in a db

```
 public class t1
{
    public string c1 { get; set; }
    public string c2 { get; set; } ...
```

2 partial views one for each model

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Database.t1
@using (Ajax.BeginForm( new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "t1div" }))
{
<fieldset>
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.c1)
     <input type="submit" value="t1view" class="btn btn-default" />
 ....

@model WebApplication2.Models.Database.t2
@using (Ajax.BeginForm( new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "t2div" }))
{
<fieldset>
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.c4)
     <input type="submit" value="t2view" class="btn btn-default" />
 ....
```

1 "composite" controller with actions to process submits from both partial views

```
public ActionResult t1view()
    {
        t1 model = new t1();....
    }
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult t1view([Bind(Include = "c1,c2,c3")] t1 t1)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)....
    }
public ActionResult t2view()
    {
        t2 model = new t2();....
    }
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult t2view([Bind(Include = "c4,c5,c6")] t2 t2)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)....
    }
```

and the index view

```
<div id="t1div">
   @Html.Action("t1view")
</div>
   <br />
<div id="t2div">
   @Html.Action("t2view")
</div>
```

So the "composite" view with the 2 partial views displays data from the tables okay. When I make some changes and hit either of the buttons, even though I have specifically called the correct action method, both the action methods under [HttpPost] get called all the time, and one of the fails as that particular partialview just sent null for the "other" table. Any ideas what am I doing wrong here? Its just been a week of me learning this - what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's hard to tell, since your code won't work as you've shown it (for instance, you don't return any view from your action methods), and your views have mismatched braces (in fact, no closing braces).. Unless you show us your ACTUAL code, we can't help you.  This pseudo code doesn't compile and only serves to send us on wild goose chases.

Comment: thanks Erik for your interest to help out - will post the full code later today, was just trying to be generic

Comment: Yes, but being generic is hiding the actual problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explicitly you have to give action property in ajax.beginForm for which action you are going to make request

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Database.t1
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("t1view","controllerName", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId =       "t1div" }))
{
<fieldset>
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.c1)
 <input type="submit" value="t1view" class="btn btn-default" />
 ....

@model WebApplication2.Models.Database.t2
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("t2view","controllerName", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "t2div" }))
{
<fieldset>
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.c4)
 <input type="submit" value="t2view" class="btn btn-default" />
....
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - so the form saves now, but then navigates out to the t1view form fully and does not display it in the composite view where the 2 partial views are displayed... any ideas ? from my little digging, it looks like I may not have the Ajax js files included - any help will be greatly appreciated.